# Does the property $A \operatorname{adj}(A) = \operatorname{adj}(A)\,A = \det(A)\,I$ define the adjugate matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Many textbooks define the adjugate matrix $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ as the transpose of the matrix of cofactors of $A$. Then they state that $A \operatorname{adj}(A) = \operatorname{adj}(A)\,A = \det(A)\,I$.

My question is: if we have a matrix $B$ such that $AB = BA = \det(A)\,I$, must $B$ be equal to $\operatorname{adj}(A)$? In other words, can we define the adjugate of $A$ as the matrix satisfying $A \operatorname{adj}(A) = \operatorname{adj}(A)\,A = \det(A)\,I$?

Comment: It does if $\det A\ne 0$. If $\det A=0$, then your proprety holds exactly for the elements of the set $\{B\in k^{n\times n}\,:\, BA=AB=0\}$, which is a vector space of dimension $(\dim\ker A)^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Take $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $B_1=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $B_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Obviously $\det A=0$ and both $AB_1=B_1A$ and$AB_2=B_2A$ are equal to $0=0\cdot I=\det A\cdot I$

For an even worse case, take $A=0$ and any matrix $B$ will satisfy $AB=BA=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is invertible, then $\newcommand{\adj}{\mathrm{adj}}\adj(A) = \det(A)A^{-1}$ is the unique solution to the equations. But if not, say if $\det(A)=0$, then there will be many matrices satisfying the equation. E.g.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}
= 0
$$
for any $a$.

Without having thought it through, I'd guess the dimensionality of the solution space depends directly on the rank of $A$. Maybe just $\dim(\ker A)$?